# Getting Wrong UTC date time (1970-01-01) in Xamarin.android using C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have an issue with UTC date time. I have existing Android application in Xamarin.android where some times I am getting wrong date time . I am generating UTC time in C# using

```
  string myUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss");
```

I am saving myUtcTime value into SQLite database column as string data type. Then fetching the utcTime from SQLite and sending it to server in JSON body.

```
  Wrong value is  1970-01-01 03:07:18.000
```

I don't know why some times I am getting 1970-01-01 on server. Please someone advise

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you need to convert back and forth (when saving into database and when retrieving based on your design).

See sample code below;

```
 public class DatetimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
 {

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return string.Empty;

    var datetime = (DateTime)value;
    //put your custom formatting here
    return datetime.ToLocalTime().ToString("g");
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    //Write your custom implementation 
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert datetime to string to store in SQLite as below

```
string dateTimeInstring = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
```

And convert datetime retrived from SQLite back to DateTime as below

```
DateTime utcDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeInstring);
DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: Does tis fixed your problem?